# How to check if any entered string is in any specific format ( ###.# )

Tags: java

I want to check if the entered string by user is in this format only-

my current code handles all formats: `##.#, ###.#, ###, ##`

but it is not able to detect when the user types `#####` or `####`

```
 // check if format: ###.# for weight and AAAA for name
    if (weight.matches("\\d{3}.\\d{1}")) {
    } else if (weight.matches("\\d{2}.\\d{1}")) {
    } else if (weight.matches("\\d{3}\\d{0}")) {
    } else if (weight.matches("\\d{2}\\d{0}")) {
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please enter weight in this format : ###.#", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

how do I detect that?

PS: I mean strictly NUMBERS when I say ##

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem.  You want to verify the number is >= 10 and <= 999, while preserving at most one decimal place precision.  Don't bother with all those regexes, just check the magnitude and round to 1 place after the user enters the value.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd else if don't have `.` _why_? and `.` is reserved char in regex.

Comment: Well, since `#` is essentially an option character, you should simply be able to check if it's a decimal value

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thought OP is considering `#` as number between `0-9`.

Comment: @coder-croc Sorry “optional digit”

Comment: replace . with [.]

Comment: `.` has  special meaning in a regex (match any character). Escape it with a backslash (double backslash inside Java strings) : `\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}`. Before fixing, your code will also match `123X4`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising your formats in English: "2 or 3 digits, optionally followed by a decimal point and a digit" then converting that to a regex:

```
[1-9]\d\d?(\.\d)?
```

In Java:

```
if (!weight.matches("[1-9]\\d\\d?(\\.\\d)?")) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "please enter weight in this format : ###.#", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Can also be written as `\\d{2,3}(\\.\\d)?`

Comment: @user9161645 In your question, you did not mention that the first digit must not be 0. In this case you can use `[1-9]\d{1,2}(\.\d)?`

Comment: do you have anything for a 2 digit number? example (1 to 99) no decimals, should not start with zero or equal "00". thanks

Comment: @user9161645 I have modified the regex (see edited answer) to require that the first digit is not a `0`